# Tax Configuration setting is not working properly

Tags: checkout, tax, shopping-cart, magento2.2.7

Shopping Cart Display Settings is not working properly.

after selecting **Including and Excluding Tax** both price is coming same as per below screen. In product listing page coming proper.

[image]

Comment: is your tax 0%? is the template using the wrong data to display?

Comment: Tax is 5% - Calculation part is proper I have problem with price to display checkout cart page and minicart section

Comment: have you checked if the setting you've chosen is overwritten by another scope? have you cleared the config-cache? you must provide code or more information. we can't help you like this.